# Greek Rendering of Joshua the son of Nun

Tags: greek, joshua, etymology

Why is Hebrew יהושע בן נון rendered into Greek as Ιησους Ναυη rather than perhaps Νουν?

The LXX seems to consistently use Ναυη for the character נון in all cases:

Joshua 1:1

> εἶπε ὁ Κύριος τῷ Ἰησοῖ υἱᾠ Ναυῆ

Joshua 2:1

> Καὶ ἀπέστειλεν Ἰησοῦς υἱὸς Ναυῆ

Numbers 13:16

> καὶ ἐπωνόμασε Μωυσῆς τὸν Αὐση υἱὸν Ναυὴ, Ἰησοῦν

Exodus 33:11

> ὁ δὲ θεράπων Ἰησοῦς υἱὸς Ναυὴ νέος οὐκ ἐξεπορευέτο ἐκ τῆς σκηνῆς

Answer (score 1):

Noteworthy is that the [Codex Sinaiticus](https://codexsinaiticus.org/) contains none of the verses in which Joshua the son of Nun is mentioned.<sup>1</sup> Therefore, we cannot compare how his name was translated into Greek in the Codex Sinaiticus versus other Greek manuscripts.

Gesenius<sup>2</sup> asserted that a copyist “probably corrupted ΝΑΥΗ for ΝΑΥΝ” („eig[entlich] wohl corrumpirt ΝΑΥΗ f[ür] ΝΑΥΝ“).

[image]

He reasoned, I assume, that a copyist at some point mistook the correct reading **ΝΑΥΝ** for **ΝΑΥΗ**. Later copyists then perpetuated the error. Why didn’t later copyists realize and correct the error? First, later copyists may not have had a Hebrew text to compare the Greek text to. They worked off whatever Greek scroll they had on hand, and from that Greek scroll, their objective was to produce additional Greek scrolls. Also, even if they had a Hebrew manuscript available, they would have had to have known how to read Hebrew.

Recall that the earliest Greek manuscripts were written in uncials or majusculars. We can examine other scripture in the Codex Sinaiticus to appreciate how similar the Greek letters Eta and Nu appear as majusculars/uncials.

In John 1:1, for example, the letters Eta and Nu appear adjacent to one another several times, as the verb ἦν (in bold) occurs three times:

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ **ἦν** ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος **ἦν** πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς **ἦν** ὁ λόγος

[image]

So, Gesenius’ assertion does not seem untenable, as the letters Eta and Nu do appear somewhat similar. It would not have taken much to mistake **ΝΑΥΝ** for **ΝΑΥΗ** if, perhaps, the copyist was working from a scroll written poorly (handwriting, ink, etc.).

Also, it’s important to note that the Septuagint we know today wasn’t the original Greek produced by the 70-72 in approximately 250 BC. It’s more or less an amalgamation of various Greek manuscripts by Origen and others. Assuming Gesenius is correct, the copyist that produced the original error was certainly working off a Greek manuscript that no longer exists. So, we don’t have the luxury of seeing how well written Joshua ben Nun’s name was in that Greek manuscript.

**Variants in the LXX**

In 1 Chronicles 7:27, the LXX has **Νουμ** for the name of Joshua’s father, rather than Ναυὴ (or something similar).

> Non his son, Jehoshua his son. <sub>King James Version, ©1769</sub>
> Νουμ υἱὸς αὐτοῦ Ιησουε υἱὸς αὐτοῦ <sub>LXX</sub>

**Other Greek Texts**

To complicate matters, the Septuagint is not the only Greek text where this supposed erroneous reading Ναυῆ occurs. The historian Josephus mentions Joshua a few times and transcribes his name into Greek as follows:

- Ἰησοῦς ὁ Ναυῆ (Wars 4.8, § 459)
- Ἰησοῦν...Ναυήκου (Antiquities 3.2, § 49)
- Ἰησοῦς..ὁ Ναυήχου (Antiquities 3.14, § 308)

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> approximately [25 verses](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=joshua%20nun&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1) <sup>2</sup> Gesenius, p. [525](https://books.google.com/books?id=a3xFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA525#v=onepage&q&f=false) |

| References |
| --- |
| Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Hebräisches und chaldäisches Handwörterbuch über das Alte Testament.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=a3xFAAAAcAAJ) 3rd ed. Leipzig: Vogel, 1828. |